# Android - DatePicker widget problem

Tags: android, android-activity, datepicker, widget

I am trying to create activity with few controls and a DatePicker widget. And I am facing one strange problem that I can not explain.

If I set activity that has only DatePicker widget shown app works. And if I set activity that has other controls without DatePicker it works too. But when I show them both I get a NullPointer Exception.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I display DatePicker widget together with other controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Presumably, you have a bug in your code. You need to find the line in your code that triggers the `NullPointerException`, then fix whatever the is causing the exception.

It is impossible to be more specific, given the limited information you supplied in your question. You might consider, in future questions, posting some of the source code and pointing out the line that is raising the `NullPointerException`.